# Multiplying double with int in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating an application for iOS and I'm stuck on a math issue. I can't figure out how to multiply a double by an int. Is this even possible?
Here's where I'm stuck:

```
double *one = 465654753464353;
int *two = 4;
double *sum = one * two;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem being asked here? Are you getting math errors, or something else?

Comment: It is clearly written that i have some problems with multiplying an double with an int and I'm asking if this is possible and if so, how?

Comment: @Parek - I know this is a little late, but Jake was asking what the problem was, because you don't say what's wrong in your question description. It's hard to help if it's unknown what's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure you mean

```
double one = 465654753464353;
```

With the asterisk sign you create a pointer to a double.

So try this:

```
double one = 465654753464353;
int two = 4;
double sum = one * two;
```

This should work.

If you meant to use pointers, have a look at @JAB's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have pointers. This is what your code should look like:

```
double one = 465654753464353;
int two = 4;
double sum = one * two;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate types of variables in objective-c. Objects and primitive data. There are many differences between the two, however, that is slightly beyond the scope of my response. 
Generally primitive datatypes do not need pointers (the * put before names).

For an easy to remember rule of thumb primitive datatypes will show up in pink like reserved words. Objects will either be blue or green (depending on wether its class you made or a class that apple made). - Colors are based off of default syntax highlighting, However, they hold true for most of the themes that ship with xCode.

ints and doubles are both primitive data types, therefore you do not need to use a star when defining them. 
Look at qegal's answer for a sample of how your code should be.